# Slow wifi and cable speeds on router

Tags: wireless-router, wifi-configuration

I have 3 wireless routers (a linsys 2600, a tenda something and an asus rtn-18u). From my isp I have an internet connection of 500Mbit/s over a PPPoE connection. To note is that if I plug the wire directly into my laptop and run a speed test I get speeds of up to 496 Mbit/s. If I plug my a wire from any router to my laptop the speeds are awefull (I get max 60Mbit/s). Also over wifi the speeds are kind of the same. The best I have managed to get is about 90Mbit/s on the asus router with the QoS option turned on.
The funny thing here is that on my phone I get speeds of 135Mbit/s (also with the asus router). Also I know that my laptop isn't the problem because I've previously downloaded with speeds of about 135Mbit/s (if it's of any importance I have an Asus G56 laptop).
I have tried to tweak with the settings and change the channel but nothing.
What exactly cand I do or what settings can I change to make it work better?

Comment: What research have you done about the routers? Are there any firmware updates available for the routers?

Comment: I updated my linksys to the latest firmware and it behaves the same and the asus one comes with the latest. I didn't bothered with the tenda too much because I knew it was slower than the other 2.